# Ionic Autenticação

Tags: java, angularjs, ionic

Gostaria de uma ajuda, pois estou a dias tentando pensar em uma maneira de fazer isso, mas ainda não consegui entender muito bem como fazer.

Tenho uma aplicação ionic, onde o acesso acontece por meio de um login que me dá um token de acesso que expira de 1 em 1 hora.

Qual a melhor maneira de guardar esse token e verificar se ele foi expirado ou não? E como faço a verificação de rotas no ionic?

Obrigada a quem puder pelo menos responder e me dar uma ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parte da verificação da Rotas, leia a seção **LIFE CYCLE** [daqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/), acho que o que você precisa é o *'ionViewCanEnter'*

Quando o usuário fizer o login e você receber o token da API, você pode armazenar este token no LocalStorage e sempre que for entrar na página (aí vai o que eu falei do "ionViewCanEnter") vc faz uma verificação pra puxar esse token do LocalStorage e ver se é válido.